# Why does Javascript not focus dynamically loaded element

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form in which some elements are loaded by ajax according to user selection. I try to insert some symbols into the textarea in the form by javascript. I use last focused method with inserttext function. Function only insert symbols into the textarea but not dynamically loaded textarea.Javascript code is at the end of body.
Thanks in advance.

```
AJAX:

function fetch_no_answer_choice(val){
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'fetch_no_answer_choice.php',
data: {'get_option' : val},
success: function (response) {document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML=response;}
});
```

}

```
fetch_no_answer_choice.php

<?php
if(isset($_POST['get_option'])){
$choice = $_POST['get_option'];
if ($choice !== 0){ 
$ans = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
$no = 0;    
for ($no = 0; $no<$choice; $no++){
echo'<textarea name = "textarea_'.$ans[$no].'" ></textarea> }
}
exit();
}
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT
    var lastFocused;
    $("textarea").focus(function() {
      lastFocused = document.activeElement;
    });

```
function insertText(text) {
  var input = lastFocused;
  console.log(input);

  if (input == undefined) { return; }
  var scrollPos = input.scrollTop;
  var pos = 0;
  var browser = ((input.selectionStart || input.selectionStart == "0") ? 
    "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
  if (browser == "ie") { 
    input.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart ("character", -input.value.length);
    pos = range.text.length;
  }
  else if (browser == "ff") { pos = input.selectionStart };

  var front = (input.value).substring(0, pos);  
  var back = (input.value).substring(pos, input.value.length); 
  input.value = front+text+back;
  pos = pos + text.length;
  if (browser == "ie") { 
    input.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart ("character", -input.value.length);
    range.moveStart ("character", pos);
    range.moveEnd ("character", 0);
    range.select();
  }
  else if (browser == "ff") {
    input.selectionStart = pos;
    input.selectionEnd = pos;
    input.focus();
  }
  input.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```